# Editor toolbar disappears whenever mxd is re-opened

Tags: arcgis-desktop, editing, arcgis-10.3, toolbar

We just switched to ArcGIS 10.3.1 from 10.2.2 at work. I've noticed that when I start to edit a feature, the Editor toolbar appears. I dock, customize it a bit, make and save some edits, and close the mxd. When I open the map again, the Editor toolbar is gone (Advanced Editing toolbar that I added remains). I start editing again, Editor toolbar pops up, minus the customization.

I can't find a setting to keep it as I added it. Never seen this behavior in previous versions of Arc. Is there a way to make it behave like previous versions?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried deleting the Normal.mxt file from your ArcGIS directory? In case you haven't, try this:

- Close all ArcGIS applications
- In Windows Explorer, navigate to your ArcMap/Templates folder. In Windows 
  7, it will look something like this:
   C:\Users\\Application Data\ESRI\Desktop10.3\ArcMap\Templates
- Rename the file called Normal.mxt to something like orig_Normal.mxt
- Open a blank ArcMap project.

This should create a new Normal.mxt void of all customizations and allow you to start over. If it works, you can simply delete your backup file that you renamed.

Answer (score -2):

This is installation problem in crack version of Arcgis 10.3.
You should reinstall your complete software with all service packs and patches.

Comment: Never heard of a crack version. What is that? I'm not on a desktop. We're set up with VDI (Virtual Device Interface). Gives a desktop feel, but all run off a server.